# how to make a container like wp's tiles desk

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

My App has a page contain some tiles layout in a canvas.

Now there is some new needs:
   I would like to make these tiles can move and zoom just like wp7 OS desk.

Can you please share with me that if there is any existing control(Library) to achieve the above functionality  or otherwise give me a Road Map how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has got a Control Library for Windows Phone that contains a control called HubTile. Have a look [here](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/hubtile.aspx) to see if the control satisfies your needs.

Comment: I am afraid what i need is not a tile. i have some tiles layout in a container. and i want to make them can move , change positon ,change size like home screen of OS .